# function arguments not found in call environment

Tags: r, metaprogramming, environment, tidyeval, quotations

I'm creating a function which takes column names as arguments and to plot survival plots. however my arguments can't be found in the calling function.

thanks in advance for your help

```
plt_survive <- function(data_in, time_var, event_var, group_var){

require(ggsurvfit)
require(survival)

  p_tittle <- as_label(group_var) # use plot title
  p <- survfit2(Surv({{time_var}}, {{event_var}}) ~ {{group_var}}, data = data_in) %>%
  ggsurvfit(linewidth = 1) +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable()
  return(p)
}

plt_survive(data_in=df_test, time_var=time_to_event_yearmonth, event_var=dfs_event, group_var=restaging)

##### Error in is_quosure(quo) : object 'restaging' not found
```

data looks like this

```
df_test <- structure(list(time_to_event_yearmonth = c(90, 80, 89, 78, 8, 
96), dfs_event = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), restaging = c("ND", "D", 
"D", NA, NA, "D"), follow_up = c("D", "D", "ND", "ND", "D", "D"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment but how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use this kind of syntax here. Replace the `survfit2` call with

```
p <- survfit2(Surv(time_var) ~ group_var, data = data_in) %>% ...
```

and call your function by explicitly specifying `df_test`:

```
plt_survive(
    data_in = df_test,
    time_var = df_test$time_to_event_yearmonth,
    event_var = df_test$dfs_event,
    group_var = df_test$restaging
)
```

[image]